# How to extract from string into a dict in python?

Tags: python

I have the following string (linebreaks, spaces, and everything):

```
<br>

                                                       Birthday
: 1/1/2014
                                            <br>
                                                                Best Win
: Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)
                        </br></br>
```

What is the best way to extract "Birthday" and "Best Win" into a dict?

```
"Birthday": "1/1/2014"
"Best Win": "Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)
```

The date could be anything, and what comes after Best Win: could be anything, but its always before the

```
</br>
```

Comment: To be fair, that markup is so awful that parsing the HTML might not be particularly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you might want to use a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I'll walk through how to work with this particular string.

Let's start by getting rid of the spaces and line breaks. I'll assume you have the string saved as `s`.

```
>>> s = s.replace('\n','') #remove newlines
>>> s
'<br>                                                       Birthday: 1/1/2014                                            <br>                                                                Best Win: Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)                        </br></br>'
```

s.
Now we can split on the `<br>` pattern to separate the pieces.

```
>>> parts = s.split('<br>')
>>> parts
['',
```

'                                                       Birthday: 1/1/2014                                            ',
 '                                                                Best Win: Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)                        ']

Now we want to get rid of empty parts, and remove those extra `</br>`s (by replacing them with the empty string.

```
>>> parts = [part.replace('</br>','') for part in parts if part != '']
>>> parts
['                                                       Birthday: 1/1/2014                                            ',
```

'                                                                Best Win: Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)                        ']

Now, we want to get rid of all those extra spaces on either side of the parts.

```
>>> parts = [part.strip(' ') for part in parts]
>>> parts
['Birthday: 1/1/2014', 'Best Win: Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)']
```

Now, finally, we can create a dictionary from the pieces.

```
>>> key_val = [ tuple(part.split(':')) for part in parts]
>>> key_val
[('Birthday', ' 1/1/2014'), ('Best Win', ' Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)')]
>>> my_dict = dict(key_val)
>>> my_dict
{'Best Win': ' Soccer, (Texas Tournament 2004)', 'Birthday': ' 1/1/2014'}
```

Obviously, you would want to use better variable names, to describe what's actually going on. I don't have a good idea of your problem, so mine are fairly nondescript.